# How to sum by multiple columns conditions (SQL)

Tags: sql

It's a bit difficult to explain what I'm trying to do (sorry for the hard to read title), but basically I want to sum repeat rows like so:

**Table A:**

```
EntryID| Country | Region | Sales 
101    | USA     | North  | $10
102    | USA     | North  | $5
103    | USA     | South  | $15
104    | USA     | South  | $10
105    | CHINA   | North  | $5
106    | CHINA   | North  | $5
107    | CHINA   | South  | $10
108    | CHINA   | South  | $20
```

**Desired Output**:

```
EntryID| Country | Region | Sales 
101    | USA     | North  | $15
103    | USA     | South  | $25
105    | CHINA   | North  | $10
107    | CHINA   | South  | $30
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what type is `sales` column?

Comment: In your desired output, are you sure that EntryID is correct for each row?  (I would imagine more than one EntryID for some rows...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL statement has to look like:

```
SELECT MIN(EntryID) AS EntryID,
  Country,
  Region,
  SUM(Sales) AS Sales
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Country,
  Region
```

Comment: Formatted the query :)

Answer (score 0):

Details are lacking, but it sounds like a simple `GROUP BY` to me:

```
select min(EntryID), Country, Region, sum(sales)
  from tbl
 group by Country, Region
```